# I have 6% weight by vol of hydrogen peroxide. How much water should i add to make it 3%

Tags: water, solutions, hydrogen

i read that to bleach hair we should use 3 percent hydrogen peroxide. the bottle i got is 100ml and says 6% w/v h2o2.so how much percentage of peroxide does it contain. how should i dilute it

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎ Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you mix equal masses of 6% hydrogenperoxide and water you will get 3% hydrogenperoxide.

Since the density of both liquids is rougly the same you can also mix equal volumes.